# `\index{...}` in footnode different from `\index{...}` in main text

Tags: footnotes, indexing, sorting

Dear all I think I have a problem with the collation of `makeidx`.

following some suggestions found here I have got in the text something like this

```
\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00855 @855A|qt}

\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00868 @868f-869b|nn{\thefootnote}}
```

the first is an `\index` entry in the text, the second in a footnote.
My problem is that even if I put the sort also on the second level of indexing it keeps keeping them separated.

I use this package information

```
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=n, title=Nomi di persone e luoghi] 
\makeindex[name=p, title=Passi citati nel testo]
\makeindex[name=t, title=Altri testi citati]
\makeindex[name=pap, title=Papiri e manoscritti citati nel testo]

\newcommand{\nn}[2]{#2 \textit{n}#1}
\newcommand{\qt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

in the `.idx` file I get this

```
\indexentry{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00855 @855A|hyperindexformat{\qt}}{8}

\indexentry{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit  {De Malignitate Herodoti}!00868 @868 b-c|hyperindexformat{\nn{33}}}{10}
```

can somebody advise me on what I am doing wrong here, please? I have tried to use `\string` after the first sort with no effect.

---

sure, sorry: this is the file I'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage{palatino}       
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,polutonikogreek,italian]{babel}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=p, title=Passi citati nel testo,columns=1]
\newcommand{\nn}[2]{#2 \textit{n}#1}
\newcommand{\qt}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document} 
(855A\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00855 @855A|qt})%
\footnote{DHM 868 B-C\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@\textit{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00868 @868 b-c|nn{\thefootnote}}}
\printindex[p]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example.

Comment: Your example works fine. It's important to know that you are using `multicol` and so the contents is balanced. You can use `\makeindex[name=p, title=Passi citati nel testo,columns=1]` to see that everything works well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment here and below. What I would like to do is to get those passages together. What I get now is "De Malignitate Herodoti 868f-869b, 13 n52" and after that  
"De Malignitate Herodoti
855A, 8" what I would instead like to have is both of these entries under De Malignitate, sorted according to the passage number only. Could you please advise me on how can I achieve this? thank you very much.

Comment: I can't provide a solution but I can tell you the error. If you don't use `textit` it works like expected: `(855A\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00855 @855A|qt})%
\footnote{DHM 868 B-C\index[p]{Plutarco!demalignitate@{De Malignitate Herodoti}!00868 @868 b-c|nn{\thefootnote}}}`

Comment: Here an very old answer of Bern Raichle, but it describes your issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/_Hwo6Hapcng

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `\index` tries hard not to tokenize its argument too early; but when the `\index` command appears in the argument to another command (in this case `\footnote`, the tokenization has already been done. Thus in the `.idx` file you get two non matching entries, one with

```
@\textit{De Malignitate Erodoti}!
```

and the other one with

```
@\textit  {De Malignitate Erodoti}!
```

A workaround is to always tokenize:

```
\newcommand{\indexp}[1]{\index[p]{#1}}
```

and using `\indexp` instead of `\index[p]`: this gives

[image]