# Indexing footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indexing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Cheese\footnote{\index{cake}cake.}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This produces the entry `cake, 1`, with no indication that the text referred to was in a footnote.  Could it be given the format `cake, 1\,n.`, and `cake 1 n.\,1` if there are more than one note on the page?

Comment: Related/duplicate? [\index inside footnote: How to propagate the footnote number correctly with index package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282591)  Also [footnote \index](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145309)

Comment: Could you tell us which question? Then we can close yours as a duplicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn, the first one.