# Formatted index entries within footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indexing, makeindex

I am using formatted subindex entries like this:

```
\index{foo!bar@\emph{bar}}
```

However, subentries appear repeated in the Index whenever I refer one within a footnote environment.

```
\footnote{foo bar\index{foo!bar@\emph{bar}}}
```

The output will be:

```
foo
   *bar*, 1
   *bar*, 3
```

But it should be

```
foo
   *bar*, 1, 3
```

At least there is one previous attempt to deal with this situation: [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145309/footnote-index) was solved using a new command `\indexp`. However, I would prefer to use the same `\index` command, because, on the one hand, it is easier to use the default command; and, on the other, I have a bunch of subfiles.

Is it possible somehow to `\renewcommand` (or something alike) the `\index`, so that it produces the desired output?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Kant, KrV\index{Kant!\emph{KrV}}
\footnote{Kant, KrV\index{Kant!\emph{KrV}}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Repeated entries]

Answer (score 1):

Use `letltxmacro`.  For `\index[p]` to work you need the `imakeidx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\indexp\index
\renewcommand\index[1]{\indexp[p]{#1}}

\begin{document}
Kant, KrV\index{Kant!\emph{KrV}}
\footnote{Kant, KrV\index{Kant!\emph{KrV}}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your original MWE wasn't producing the index. So I edited it and deleted the `[p]`, for I only use one index. This way it works as intended