# Reledmac/Reledmac: duplicating index entries

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, reledmac, reledpar

I have a very strange issue with Reledpar and Imakeidx. If you put the same object into the same index it gets duplicated if the entry is located in the Endonotes.

More strange, the issue appears just with names like {Pippo \textsc{iii}}, and not with single words names.

I already tried things like Pippo \textsc{iii}@Pippo \textsc{iii}, but it didn't work.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Garamond Premier Pro}  
\newfontfamily\SlantedFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont[]{Garamond Premier Pro}            
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[]{greek}          

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INDICI %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{morewrites}                             % Risolve il problema di Reledmac con gli indici multipli
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\makeindex[name=nomi, intoc=true, title=Indice dei nomi]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI RELEDMAC / RELEDPAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noledgroup,                                 % Escludo l'uso di note dentro minipage
            noeledsec,                                  % Non uso comandi di sezionamento tipo chapter, section, etc all'interno del txt critico
            series={A,B}]{reledmac}                     % Restringo le serie di note alle sole che uso
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}            % settaggi di sincronia. % advancedshiftedpstarts


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Pippo\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc{iii}}

\cleardoublepage

\selectlanguage{greek}  
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\pstart 
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Afootnote{πολιστίχοις }} \edtext{ἐσπαρμένοι}{\Afootnote{ἐπαρμένοι FP ἐγκατεσπαρμένοι J}} λόγοις, δι’ ὧν ἡ ὀφρὺς κατασπᾶται τῶν τὴν ἀλήθειαν ἐν ἀδικίᾳ κατέχειν φιλονεικούντων. \pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\selectlanguage{italian}        
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\normalsize
\pstart
Hello my dear friend Pippo\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc{iii}} you are a good, \edtext{friend}{\Bendnote{Pippo\textsc{\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc{iii}}}}} and that's all.\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages              

\doendnotes{B}
\printindex[nomi]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting question! To make it easier to answer, maybe you can make the MWE a bit more minimal? For example, is the Greek part needed? And the font specifications? Line numbering settings? Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372308/formatted-index-entries-within-footnotes/.

Comment: I see the problem. I try to solve it.

Comment: Here the tissue. https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/754 I have no idea for now to the method to solve the problem.

Comment: It is related to two tex problems https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420654/https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420651/

Comment: I wait for this question

Comment: It's a big problem. If we can't find any solution is there at least the chance to fix the thing manually somehow?

Comment: If the problem is caused by a different number of spaces perhaps using `makeindex`'s `-c` switch might help.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix, if you write all the entries in the "wrong way", namely with two spaces between \textsc and {iii}, you can bypass the problem.

I know that this is not a solution but just cheating, of course

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright]{book}%openany

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Garamond Premier Pro}  
\newfontfamily\SlantedFont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\setmainfont[]{Garamond Premier Pro}            
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Garamond Premier Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        
    \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguage[]{greek}          

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INDICI %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{morewrites}                             % Risolve il problema di Reledmac con gli indici multipli
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\makeindex[name=nomi, intoc=true, title=Indice dei nomi]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDI RELEDMAC / RELEDPAR %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[noledgroup,                                 % Escludo l'uso di note dentro minipage
            noeledsec,                                  % Non uso comandi di sezionamento tipo chapter, section, etc all'interno del txt critico
            series={A,B}]{reledmac}                     % Restringo le serie di note alle sole che uso
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts, nomaxlines]{reledpar}            % settaggi di sincronia. % advancedshiftedpstarts


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INIZIO DOCUMENTO %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Pippo\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc  {iii}}

\cleardoublepage

\selectlanguage{greek}  
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\pstart 
Ἐν πολλοῖς μέν εἰσιν οἱ ἔλεγχοι \edtext{πολυστίχοις}{\Afootnote{πολιστίχοις }} \edtext{ἐσπαρμένοι}{\Afootnote{ἐπαρμένοι FP ἐγκατεσπαρμένοι J}} λόγοις, δι’ ὧν ἡ ὀφρὺς κατασπᾶται τῶν τὴν ἀλήθειαν ἐν ἀδικίᾳ κατέχειν φιλονεικούντων. \pend

\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\selectlanguage{italian}        
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\numberpstarttrue
\normalsize
\pstart
I want to kill all these indents, please. Poiché dunque Pippo\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc  {iii}} la tua ricerca, magnifica e cara a Dio, ha richiesto una sinossi degli argomenti per farne uno schema, \edtext{cosa}{\Bendnote{Pippo\textsc{\index[nomi]{Pippo \textsc  {iii}}}}} per noi gradita alla divina provvidenza, vedrai che tale obiettivo non indegno del tuo amor di Dio né della tua richiesta sarà perseguito.\pend

\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages              

\doendnotes{B}
\printindex[nomi]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if it can be useful, but it's happening the same thing even outside Eledmac/Eledpar, so I think it's an issue related to the package Imakeidx