# \write : maximum lines'

Tags: tex-core, write

In [the ledmac documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ledmac/ledmac.pdf#page=123), Peter Wilson wrote that, when writing to the `.end` file (which stores the endnote), it transforms all spaces to line breaks.

> We change
>       `\newlinechar` so that in the file every space becomes the start of a new line; this
>       generally ensures that a long note doesn’t exceed restrictions on the length of lines
>       in files.

Is there any restriction in the length of file (today, with modern engines)? I don't see anything in

This has an influence on [Reledmac/Reledmac: duplicating index entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420502/reledmac-reledmac-duplicating-index-entries)

Comment: The limit should be the “buffer size”, set to 200000 in TeX Live. Peter Wilson took a very drastic decision, but when `endnote` (from which he took the code for `ledmac`, IIRC) was written, memory was very scarce and the buffer size used to be rather small.

Comment: We have had issues with it in memoir, people complained that they hit the limit on line lengths, and we adapted the same approach.

Comment: but that provoke https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420502/reledmac-reledmac-duplicating-index-entries

Comment: @egreg : where can I found all defaut setting of TeXLive? and for Miktex?

Comment: @Maïeul I guess `kpsewhich -var-value buf_size` works on both systems from a shell.

Comment: @Maïeul The `buf_size` plays a role when files are input, i.e., when the endnotes are read in again. Are you aware of Peter Breitenlohner's [article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-1/tb27breitenlohner.pdf)
where lines keep the line breaks of the TeX file? This should work
on any author's OS: What can be placed on one line in the input is
kept together and can be reread for the endnotes.

Comment: @UdoWermuth No I didn't know it, I think, it is better way. I will implement it as soon as possible.